AWS IAM Role Switch Only Works in a few regions
I'm having trouble switching roles in AWS IAM. The role, named "S3RestrictedRole," allows me to assume it from us-east-1 and us-west-2, but attempts to switch from any other region fail.

Role Trust Relationship:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::533267091808:user/user_1"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}


S3RestrictedRole Policy:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "test1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}


user_1 Policy (No Policy Attached): There is no separate policy attached to user_1. Permissions rely solely on the trust relationship with "S3RestrictedRole".

Steps Taken:
Verified the trust relationship and policy configurations (provided above).
Confirmed "user_1" doesn't have a separate policy.
S3 bucket location us-east-1.
Despite the "s3:*" permission and lack of region-specific restrictions in the configurations, why can I only switch roles from us-east-1 and us-west-2? Are there any potential resource access controls or other factors I might be missing that could explain this regional restriction?
Additional Information:
MFA is not enabled for "user_1" or "S3RestrictedRole".
I suspect the issue might lie with resource access controls, but "s3:*" seems to grant broad access.
Video link of me trying to switch from different locations
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Any chance this is simply a propagation delay? Did you retry later?
